# Integrating the Spotify SDK with Android

Tags: android, sdk, integration, spotify

I want to know if it is compulsory to install the Spotify app when integrating the Spotify SDK with Android. Can anyone help me out with this? I am using the new Spotify SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/), yes it is a requirement to install Spotify to use their Mobile Development SDK

> App Remote SDK requires the Spotify app to be installed on the device.
>   Install the latest version of Spotify from Google Play on the device
>   you want to use for development. Run the Spotify app and login or sign
>   up.

Comment: Indeed, the music playback needs the app installed, it's the same for iOS